# Regarding will_paginate using an explicit "per page" limit - Rails 4.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For instance, I have got a Post model and I will achieve per page limit of 10 in the way as below;

```
Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

But my question is, How would I limit pages randomly.

For example, for the first page I want to show 10 records and on the second page I want to show 15 records and so on.

How would I implement this in my rails application.

posts_controller.rb

```
    class PostsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

      # GET /posts
      # GET /posts.json
      def index
    @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page])
    dynamic_paging = {"1" => 10, "2"=> 15, "3"=> 20, "4"=>25 }
    per_page_after_four = 30
    params[:page] = params[:page] || 1
    if params[:page] < 5
      @posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => dynamic_paging[params[:page]])
    else
      @posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => per_page_after_four)
    end
  end
```

index.html.erb

```
<center><%= will_paginate @posts %></center>
```

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using following code you can achieve this, but you need to decide that the limit for example, after page 4 all pages should contain per_page 30.

```
dynamic_paging = {"1" => 10, "2"=> 15, "3"=> 20, "4"=>25 }
per_page_after_four = 30
params[:page] = params[:page] || 1
if params[:page] < 5
  @posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => dynamic_paging[params[:page]])
else
  @posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => per_page_after_four)
end
```

## update

And if you want to set the per_page from your view than here is the updated solution.

use select on the view.

```
<%= select_tag :per_page, options_for_select([10,15,20,25], params[:per_page].to_i),
   :onchange => "if(this.value){window.location='?per_page='+this.value;}" %>
```

and in the controller.

```
@per_page = params[:per_page] || Post.per_page || 20
@posts = Post.paginate( :per_page => @per_page, :page => params[:page])
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I used the topmost option I get the following error; undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass around this line of code that is if params[:page] < 5. And I put that code in my Post controllers index action.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117513/discussion-between-muhammad-yaseen-and-power).

Comment: Dear Mr.Power, waiting for your reply.

Comment: Dear Mr.Power, waiting for your reply as I want to make clear something.

Answer (score 0):

Revised the index view as below;

```
def index
   dynamic_paging = {"1" => 10, "2"=> 15, "3"=> 20, "4"=>25 }
    params[:page] = params[:page] || 1
    if params[:page].to_i < 5
      @posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => dynamic_paging[params[:page].to_s])
   end
  end
```